# Can't update the new position in the onTouch event

Tags: java, android, layout, ontouch

I'm a beginner, but I want to create a game. Now I am doing the moving function for my hero. When i touch the image and move it to the right side, the hero will go to the right side from the original position by 100dp per second, but its can't work.

Below is the code that i use as my moving function :

```
public View.OnTouchListener move = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    private float x, y;
    private int mx, my, hx, hy;

    public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {

            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            mx = (int) (event.getRawX() - x);
            my = (int) (event.getRawY() - y);

        } else if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)) {

            hx = (int) (event.getRawX() - x);
            hy = (int) (event.getRawY() - y);
            v.layout(hx, hy, hx + v.getWidth(), hy + v.getHeight());

        } else if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {

            while (hx > mx) {
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mx += 100;
                        v.layout(mx, my, mx + v.getWidth(), my + v.getHeight());
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
        Log.e("x =", String.valueOf(x) + "    y =" + String.valueOf(y));
        Log.e("hx =", String.valueOf(hx) + "    hy =" + String.valueOf(hy));
        Log.e("mx =", String.valueOf(mx) + "    my =" + String.valueOf(my)); 
        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_UP`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

//edit layout params according to your need
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: do this in ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks you, it get move now :)